# JQuery - Don't execute on postback

Tags: jquery, postback

I have some code to fade in a message to the user in certain scenarios. This one ASPX page does a postback, and clears the page with success or failure based on fields filled out by the user.

I KNOW I'll probably start a huge war, on how I should be checking the DOM instead of the browser for the existence of mozilla. That's fine, I get that. But I just want to run the `fadeIn()` one time, when the page is created on the initial load.

```
if ($.browser.mozilla != true) {
     $("#dim").fadeIn();
}
```

I'm like on day three of jQuery here, so I've done some searches but not finding what I'm trying to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hidden field to keep the state of postback and use that hidden field before running the javascript code.

*In html*

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnIsPostBack" value="false" />
```

*In code behind*

```
if(Page.IsPostBack)
    hdnIsPostBack.Value = "true";
else
    hdnIsPostBack.Value = "false";
```

*In javascript*

```
if( $('#<%= hdnIsPostBack.ClientID %>').val() == "false")
{
    //Your code here
    if ($.browser.mozilla != true) {
       $("#dim").fadeIn();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. Makes sense now thinking more about it. And thanks for not being an ass like so many people on here. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple as it looks

If you want to have `fadein` at initial page load then you can try with the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dim").fadeIn();
});
```

one more thing, if your page is doing postbacks then you might want to get the same in such case you can try this from your `<Page>.cs`

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,GetType(),"<anything as key>","$('#dim').fadeIn();",true);
```

Let me know if the answer is not relevant.